# Emitting only after set of events?

Tags: rxjs

I'm trying to do something like the following - B is being emitted independently of A, but I want to emit when there is a B that happens after an A (in that order).

```js
----A--------A-->
B--B--B--B----B->

------B-------B->
```

Thanks!

Comment: what about creating a listener for A and when the first value of A comes in then within the listener you create a listener for B?

Comment: You are looking for sample: http://rxmarbles.com/#sample

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case you have a **hot observable** and you want to emit the values from `B`, then you might want to use a `switchMap` in combination with a `take(1)`: (basically just the 3 last lines are relevant, the upper part is just mocking some data-stream)

```js
// Mocking A and B
const streamA$ = Rx.Observable
  .interval(2500)
  .do(() => console.log("Emitting on A => TAKE NEXT B!!!"))
  .share();
const streamB$ = Rx.Observable
  .interval(1200)
  .do(data => console.log("Emitting on B: " + data))
  .publish();
streamB$.connect();
// \End of mocking

streamA$
  .switchMap(() => streamB$.take(1))
  .subscribe(data => console.info("Took value: " + data));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

---

If you have **cold observables** you could use [`window`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-window) in combination with `map`:

```js
// Mocking A and B
const streamA$ = Rx.Observable
  .interval(4000)
  .do(() => console.log("Emitting on A => TAKE NEXT B!!!"));
const streamB$ = Rx.Observable
  .interval(900)
  .do(data => console.log("Emitting on B: " + data));
// \End of mocking

streamB$.window(streamA$)
  .skip(1)                 // skip the first window, since this will be emitted before A emitted the first time
  .mergeMap(win => win.take(1)) // each window should have at most 1 emission
  
  .subscribe(data => console.info("Took value: " + data));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that works nicely if `streamB` is hot. If not, it won't

Comment: True - though I can't really follow the downvote since this information was not stated in the question that you were looking to work with cold observables

Comment: I downvoted nobody. Actually I am upvoting you because the answer is useful, which is what upvoting is supposed to mean

Comment: Yes, I thought so already - anyways, someone did - it was more directed to whomever made the downvote, I've been updating my answer meanwhile with a block for cold observables ;)