# RxJS: Sample the events of an observable after the events of another observable

Tags: javascript, rxjs

In RxJS we have the `sample` operator that, according to [the docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-sample):

> Emits the most recently emitted value from the source Observable whenever another Observable, the notifier, emits.

I want something similar, but with the values emmited **after** the notifier emits.

With sample:

```
Stream:   -a---b-c---d--
Notifier: ---x-----x----

Result:   -a-----c------
```

With what I want:

```
Stream:   -a---b-c---d--
Notifier: ---x-----x----

Result:   -----b-----d--
```

Is there an operator or combination of operators that does this?

Comment: Try something like this `Notifier.switch(() => Stream.take(1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a complete answer to that question here : [Emitting only after set of events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43188180/emitting-only-after-set-of-events)

As Yuri mentioned in his comment, if your `Stream` is hot, you can use `Stream.take(1)`, if it is cold, have a look at the answer linked thereabove. It uses the `window` operator.